# Wrapper class in java is it a class with primitive data type as member?

Tags: java, wrapper, primitive-types

I want to know how Integer class works:
Consider

```
Integer number=2;
```

Does this mean, "Integer" class has a constructor like mentioned below and it stores the int value in it? Please explain.

```
class Integer
{
    int a;

    public Integer (int a)
    {
        this.a=a;
    }
}
```

Comment: No reason to guess what Integer class has. Take a look at the source code yourself http://kickjava.com/src/java/lang/Integer.java.htm

Comment: One exception would be `Void` which doesn't have a public constructor (or a value inside)

Answer (score 6):

Pretty close.  Check out [the source code for Integer](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html) (apparently from Harmony so the Sun/Oracle JVM may be a bit different).  Autoboxing conversions (when you assign a primitive to a wrapper class) use the equivalent of valueOf, which caches "common" integers and creates new ones for the rest.

Comment: yep it's basically identical, except they used "value" instead of "a".  See lines 38, and 83-85

Answer (score 2):

`javac` generates code to call `Integer.valueOf(int)` which may or may not construct a new `Integer` or just reuse an existing one. In the JLS this is covered by ["boxing conversions"](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190697).

Comment: @ranjanarr Depends upon implementation. It's in the `src.zip` for the usual Oracle JDKs. The exact code has changed between updates.

Answer (score 1):

That means [auto boxing](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/basic_types/autoboxing.html) is in place.

Comment: @rananarr - Take a look at my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can always find the latest OpenJDK Integer class [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java):

The relevant field is (from line 645):

```
/**
 * The value of the {@code Integer}.
 *
 * @serial
 */
private final int value;
```